# How to select Distinct / Group By child property in both LINQ method and syntax?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have class

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int ParentID { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public int ChildID { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentID")]
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

I need something equivalent of

```
SELECT
    Child.Grade
FROM
    Parent
    INNER JOIN Child ON
        Parent.ParentID = Child.ParentID
WHERE
    Parent.ParentID = 1
GROUP BY
    Child.Grade
```

And

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Child.Grade
FROM
    Parent
    INNER JOIN Child ON
        Parent.ParentID = Child.ParentID
WHERE
    Parent.ParentID = 1
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to join to the parent, because you can just use `Child.ParentId`

Anyway, you can do this:

```
var result = db.Set<Child>().Where(c => c.Parent.ParentId = 1).GroupBy(c => c.Grade);
```

Or without the join;

```
var result = db.Set<Child>().Where(c => c.ParentId = 1).GroupBy(c => c.Grade);
```

And distinct is simply:

```
var result = db.Set<Child>().Where(c => c.ParentId = 1).Select(c => c.Grade).Distinct();
```